# Merging two stings inn python in a back-tic

Tags: python

let's say I have two strings:

```
 str1 = “Hello”
 str2 = “World”
```

I wish to merge them, not in a quotation mark but in a **backtick**

[image]

Comment: `"\`{} {}\`".format(str1, str2)` ?

Comment: this makes no sense: strings are defined with `"` or `'`. If you want `\``, it has to be a character inside the string (as suggested by zwer).

Comment: @Julien yes i know but this is what op is asking

Comment: thanks zwer I am happy to accept your answer if you post it below.  Julien, I had a code that had to replace with some stings inside backtic. The answer works for me.

Comment: if this is what you want, then you can also use this if you need to concatenate many of them: `"\`" + " ".join([str1, str2, str3, ...]) + "\`"`